# Developing using solr in Eclipse (CentOS 7)

Tags: eclipse, solr, server

Are there any guides available for using solr 6.x inside of eclipse? I know since Solr 5 that using solr with servers such as Tomcat is no longer supported, but all of the documentation I can find refers to simply starting a server from the command line and indexing manually from there. How can I find out more about progrematically accessing my solr server?

Comment: You can get the solr core and solrj jars to use and extend the functionality provided by solr.

Comment: http://www.solrtutorial.com/solrj-tutorial.html